# I want to move drivers out of my archive manager/file roller

Tags: drivers, synaptic

I want to move drivers that are in my archive manager/ file roller to Update manager, ubuntu software center or synaptic package manager

Answer (score 1):

Update manager, Software center and Synaptic all only access software present in one of the package repositories you've added to your system.

There is no easy way to have them use a archive file from the archive manager (you'd need to convert the driver archive to a .deb file and set up your own package repository for that).

For some drivers there are already (unofficial) package repositories, so if you tell us which driver you want to add maybe someone knows a repository for it.

Comment: Thanks for the response the driver is= driver-x86_32-4.4.0.tar.gz For a matrox g400, thanks